# Ajax with polymer. render after response

Tags: ajax, polymer, polymer-1.0

I try to make ajax with polymer iron-ajax.

My problem is that when Is their is some elements that can be render only after I received  response, otherwise their is not data to render.

How can I "stop" the render of the element until their is response?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two options:

1. Add a conditional `hidden`attribute to the div or elements you want hidden before the ajax call is completed:

   `<div hidden$="[[!response]]"></div>`

   or handle visibility using a computed binding

   `<div hidden$="[[_computeIsHidden(response)]]"`
2. Wrap your content in a `dom-if` template:

   `<template is="dom-if" if="[[_computeIsHidden(response)]]">`

Comment: Their is a way to implement this computeIsHidden function in the main    and not create custom element for this?

Answer (score 1):

Just:
`<template is="dom-if" if="[[response]]">`